# How to expose "generic" C# collection to COM

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop

I have an API which I have developed a C# client for which converts HTTP GET requests into C# objects.

I have made the client COM visible as I need it in VB6, the issue here is that generic collections does not work over COM. I have made a "fix" for this by making my own implementation of a collection except it is not generic.

This means I have a class named *[Class]*_Collection for each of my classes, this just means I have a collection without the generic class.

This works well except our API is quite large with quite a few different objects, so it would be nice if I did not have to write the implementation for every class in our API.

I have been experiementing with a generic base class or generic interface which I can inherit, but as previously stated COM does not like generic classes.
I also require an IDispatch interface to expose functionality so that the class functions are exposed in VB6.

Is there a way in which I can write the implementation for all my collections and just inherit that functionality everywhere it is needed?

Comment: ArrayList https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist used to be compatible with COM (I've not tested with .NET core/5/6+ but I don't see why it wouldn't work). But it's not "generic" as in .NET generics

Comment: I think you will be stuck having to create one collection class for each of your classes but once you go down that road, you can create a base collection class that handles most of the "collection" work. This base collection can use a List or Dictionary and provide plain methods to access the data. You might have to write your own enumerator though.

Comment: Yeah, I tried making a base class which handles most of the collection functionality, but since the IDispatch interface cant be read when it is not directly on the class I have had some issues with this. It is quite important for me to have the functionality exposed. As the VB6 editor which is going to use this library has autocompletion and the developers should know instantly what functionality is available to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are indeed incompatible with COM, as far as I know there is no way around that restriction in itself.

The approach I've used as a simple workaround is to add wrapper properties specifically for COM-interop purposes.

Example:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public List<int> SomeNumbers {get; set;}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Obsolete("Use this for COM interop only")]
public IList SomeNumbersCOM => SomeNumbers;
```

This has the benefit of being fairly simple, does not actually copy any data, and functions through COM. However it is obviously not typesafe since within VB6 the entries of `SomeNumbersCOM` will just appear to be `object`. But VB6 isn't especially typesafe anyway, so this may not really be a big problem. And at least the real strongly typed collection can be used within C#. The `Obsolete` helps to enforce this.

The mild loss of type safety hasn't been a real issue in my experience. You still can assert the correct type on the VB side; e.g., use a `Long` variable when getting values out of the `SomeNumbersCOM` list..

You don't have to add very much code that isn't just boilerplate. e.g., you don't have to actually code collection classes or replicate their internal logic.

---

Instead of wrapping properties in the same class, you could create an entire wrapper class, which would be a bit cleaner for the C# consumers.

Creating an entirely separate COM-visibility wrapper assembly (which contains all those wrapper classes) would be an even stronger way to mandate that the wrappers are NOT used from elsewhere on the C# side.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea to use wrapper classes and create a COM enabled Library with the wrapper classes and then let the C# consumers have access to the full functionality instead of restricting them because it needs to be backwards compatible. This is the way I will go, thanks!