# Unable to expose a List property via com for C++

Tags: c#, com

Take this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MSAToolsLibrary.DatabaseManagers
{
    [Guid("078BC241-9999-4E53-BD30-1D98F29AF341")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ITimeInfo
    {
        DateTime CurrentMeetingTime { get; set; }
        DateTime CurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom { get; set; }
        bool MeetSameTime { get; set; }
        List<TimeChange> TimeChanges { get; set; }
    }

    [Guid("11BDCA76-4392-4568-A87A-797C9A78E5D2")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class TimeInfo : ITimeInfo
    {
        private bool _MeetSameTime;
        private DateTime _CurrentMeetingTime;
        private DateTime _CurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom;
        private List<TimeChange> _TimeChanges;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public bool MeetSameTime { get => _MeetSameTime; set => _MeetSameTime = value; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime CurrentMeetingTime { get => _CurrentMeetingTime; set => _CurrentMeetingTime = value; }
        [XmlElement("CurrentMeetingTime")]
        public string CurrentMeetingTimeString
        {
            get { return this.CurrentMeetingTime.ToString("HH:mm"); }
            set { this.CurrentMeetingTime = DateTime.Parse(value); }
        }
        public bool ShouldSerializeCurrentMeetingTimeString()
        {
            return !_MeetSameTime;
        }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "date")]
        public DateTime CurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom { get => _CurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom; set => _CurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom = value; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeCurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom()
        {
            return !_MeetSameTime;
        }

        public List<TimeChange> TimeChanges { get => _TimeChanges; set => _TimeChanges = value; }
        public bool ShouldSerializeTimeChanges()
        {
            return !_MeetSameTime;
        }

        public TimeInfo()
        {
            _MeetSameTime = true;
            _TimeChanges = new List<TimeChange>();
        }

        public TimeInfo(bool meetSameTime, DateTime currentMeetingTime, DateTime currentMeetingTimeValidFrom, List<TimeChange> timeChanges)
        {
            _MeetSameTime = meetSameTime;
            _CurrentMeetingTime = currentMeetingTime;
            _CurrentMeetingTimeValidFrom = currentMeetingTimeValidFrom;
            _TimeChanges = timeChanges;
        }
    }
}
```

The `TimeChanges` is currently defined like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MSAToolsLibrary.DatabaseManagers
{
    public class TimeChange
    {
        private int _Months;
        private DateTime _Time;

        [XmlAttribute]
        public int Months { get => _Months; set => _Months = value; }
        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime Time { get => _Time; set => _Time = value; }
        [XmlAttribute("Time")]
        public string TimeString
        {
            get { return this.Time.ToString("HH:mm"); }
            set { this.Time = DateTime.Parse(value); }
        }

        public TimeChange()
        {

        }

        public TimeChange(int months, DateTime time)
        {
            _Months = months;
            _Time = time;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles fine, but in my CPP project that uses this DLL via COM I have no access to the `TimeChanges` property. So I thought I would extract an interface for the `TimeChange` and I get a compiler warning:

> warning : Type library exporter warning processing 'MSAToolsLibrary.DatabaseManagers.ITimeInfo.get_TimeChanges(#0), MSAToolsLibrary'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type instance in a signature. Generic code may not be exported to COM.
> warning : Type library exporter warning processing 'MSAToolsLibrary.DatabaseManagers.ITimeInfo.set_TimeChanges(value), MSAToolsLibrary'. Warning: Type library exporter encountered a generic type instance in a signature. Generic code may

What changes do I need to make to expose the `TimeChanges` property so I can add / remove items from the list?

---

At the moment I added a function:

```
public void AddTimeChange(int months, DateTime time)
{
    _TimeChanges.Add(new TimeChange(months, time));
}
```

and exposed that.

Comment: expose array ...

Comment: @Selvin Not sure what you mean. The `List` is exposed.

Comment: `TimeChange[]` instead `List<TimeChange>` ...edit: I see you wana "add / remove" ... then expose it as non generic `IList`

Comment: I do this just up in the interface? I have a work around but not ideal.

Comment: [not tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013699/how-to-expose-generic-c-sharp-collection-to-com)